I am getting XHR failed error on after I downloaded VSC on my new macbook

I recently bought a new MacBook M3 Pro and downloaded Visual Studio Code on it. However, I'm encountering an error that I can't resolve. I've looked through various posts on Stack Overflow and tried the suggested solutions, but the issue persists. Most of the posts are focused on fixes for Windows OS, which isn't helpful for my situation. This is the first time I am having this issue. I have a windows PC and VSC is fine on it.

I was able to resolve the issue. I tried rebooting, various troubleshooting methods, and even reinstalling VS Code, but nothing worked. Eventually, I installed an older version from January 2024, and it worked fine. I then updated to the latest version (1.91.1) from within VS Code, and updating to the latest version did not bring back the issue.

